# How can you make a df column hashable if it is currently an series object?

Tags: series, hashable

I am trying to write a function and for loop to take in the country name and convert it into country code and later write a for loop to place the different countries into their correct continent. I get an error saying that series are not hashable.  How do I change a series into something hashable? The data is from kaggle: world happiness.  Here is my code:

```
def ctry_code_convert(val1):
    ctry_converted=pc.country_name_to_country_alpha2(val1, cn_name_format='default')
    return (ctry_converted)


for i in range(len(happiness['Country name'])):
    ctry_cde=ctry_code_convert(happiness['Country name'])
    happiness['Country_Code']=ctry_cde
```

TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
I tried to change it to tuple and str so I but I am not sure why neither work.

Comment: show us the struct and dtypes of your df